overwriting border style hidden to solid dont work
My sample code, test it yourself:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#timeline {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#timeline td {
  border-style: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

#timeline td.tl_date {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-right-style: solid !important;
}
<table id="timeline">
  <tr>
    <td class="tl_date">
      <div>2024</div>
      <div>January 1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="tl_text">New Year Celebration</td>
  </tr>
</table>



border-style: hidden affects my table. Border is not shown even though border-style is overwritten from hidden to solid. What is going one here, please explain

remove the border-collapse: collapse;

Remove border-style: hidden; Not sure what you are doing there.

Is this the problem? See the documentation 'hidden:
Like the none keyword, displays no border. Unless a background-image is set, the computed value of the same side's border-width will be 0, even if the specified value is something else. In the case of table cell and border collapsing, the hidden value has the highest priority: if any other conflicting border is set, it won't be displayed.' from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style

When border-style is set to hidden, it not only hides the border but also prevents any border from being displayed, even if you try to override it with another border style using !important.
Thats why the border-style: hidden set on the #timeline td  , prevents border-right-style: solid !important in the #timeline td.tl_date from working
Instead, I suggest you target the td.tl_date
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#timeline {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#timeline td {
  border-style: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

#timeline td.tl_date {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black !important;
}

#timeline td.tl_date {
  border-style: solid !important; 
}

